# What flags to use with rsync to make it delete a file /dest/foo and replace it with the directory /src/foo?

Tags: rsync

What flags should I use to make rsync delete a *file* `/dest/foo` and replace it with the *directory* `/src/foo`?

Also, the reverse, replace *directory* `/dest/foo` with *file* `/src/foo`?

Comment: `--delete` flag deletes files on destination that do not exist in source any more. This is the only way for rsync to delete anything on destination. For more detailed solution, you will have to give more detail of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The underlying problem I am trying to solve is this: I am backing up an ecryptfs .Private directory, and I am getting this error: rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/media/backup-drive/.ecryptfs/me/.Private/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWauvZ5wbdfe2-QOL2Nuj-trN7RR-6HYoPwybY44trVn7Q9TBSz5lJdlK---/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWauvZ5wbdfe2-QOL2Nuj-trN7RR-6HYoPwyWaZDb.bf-YQMYZtD9IcbFE--/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FXauvZ5wbdfe2-QOL2Nuj-trN7RR-6HYoPwydZNv.BncNcSdnscrZOl99wwZQUmf6y53RD8Uv82pbog-": Not a directory (20)

Comment: So it's almost impossible to tell on what it is choking; I googled for the basic error: `rsync recv_generator: failed to stat Not a directory (20)`, but this didn't lead to much I could apply in my situation.

Comment: I forgot to state that the rsync command I am using is `rsync -avvP --ignore-existing --recursive --delete /home/.ecryptfs/me/.Private .` (where $PWD is /media/backup-drive/.ecryptfs/me)

Comment: Just an idea. Directory name looks pretty complicated. Can any filesystem have a directory with such a name? Maybe the problem is linked to destination filesystem capabilities. Try to copy it to another directory on the same partition, too see that it can be copied. If that works, find out why destination cannot hold the files.

Comment: Another option would be to use tar with incremental feature. In that way, you backup the whole directory, and then only changes. Strange directory names are hidden in tar file and backups are not so big if you don't change all files every time. I usually make a script to do a full backup on the first day of the month and incremental backups through out the month.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$ tree -F
.
|-- dest/
|   `-- foo
`-- src/
    `-- foo/

3 directories, 1 file
```

Doing `rsync -r src/foo dest` would replace the file `dest/foo` with the directory `src/foo`:

```
$ rsync -r src/foo dest
$ tree -F
.
|-- dest/
|   `-- foo/
`-- src/
    `-- foo/

4 directories, 0 file
```

You would most often want to use the `-a` (`--archive`) option though, which implies `-r` (`--recursive`) and also preserves meta-data.

---

The reverse works in a similar way:

```
$ tree -F
.
|-- dest/
|   `-- foo/
`-- src/
    `-- foo

3 directories, 1 file
```

The command is the same, although `-r` is not actually needed here (you can't recurse down into a file):

```
$ rsync -r src/foo dest
$ tree -F
.
|-- dest/
|   `-- foo
`-- src/
    `-- foo

2 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Please see my comments in response to @nobody above.

Comment: @Roadowl Please update your question rather than adding info in comments. As this seems to be related to the particular encryption setup that you have, tag the question appropriately and give the correct context in the question. Feeding us context in comments little by little is not helping anyone.

Comment: As is removing tags.

Comment: @Roadowl The question, as formulated when I removed the [tag:linux] tag, had _nothing_ to do with Linux.  In fact, my answer would be appropriate for the question as it's currently formulated. This has been tested and it works on OpenBSD, Solaris and Ubuntu.  See also this recent Meta discussion: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/what-is-the-linux-tag-for